# Pass data from Helper Data to Knockout JS file Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, helper, data

How i can pass helper data to Knockout JS to show it on my html file. Actually i am working on Checkout page and i want to show the name of product owner on checkout summary.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In this most case, we need to pass data to Javascript global variable.